# How do you get data sets from papers?

Tags: dataset

Specifically, I'm looking for the Artificial Insemination by Donor data set from this paper:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2680488.pdf

Is there a database somewhere to get data sets from papers? I can't seem to find it through googling.

Comment: You are unlikely to find that dataset online, especially given the year of publication (1999). My guess is that your best bet is to try contacting the authors, although there's also a good chances that this data is protected by something like HIPAA agreements (couldn't actually read the paper due to paywall).